# Jetpack Compose navigation NavController.popBackStack() not working properly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation, jetpack-compose-navigation

When working with Compose Navigation and calling `NavController.popBackStack()` multiple times on the first shown Composable (`startDestination`) the backnavigation does not work anymore. For example when navigating to another Composable from this point on and then calling `popBackStack` does not have an effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some Reason the size of the `NavController.backQueue` is at least 2 even though it's supposed to only show one Composable. If popping the backstack lower than that, the navigation does not seem to work anymore. (I don't know why)

Therefore I wrote the following simple extension function which prevents popping the BackQueue lower than 2:

```kotlin
fun NavController.navigateBack(onIsLastComposable: () -> Unit = {}) {
    if (backQueue.size > 2) {
        popBackStack()
    } else {
        onIsLastComposable()
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```kotlin
val navController = rememberNavController()
...
navController.navigateBack {
    //do smth when Composable was last one on BackStack
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simply**, create an *extension function* `NavHostController.navigateBackTo()` and call from anywhere (even from `@Composable` body) to `popBackStack()` until first:

```
fun NavHostController.navigateBackTo() {
    while(backQueue.size > 2) {
        popBackStack()
    }
} 

....

// Call to popBackStack() until first.
navController.navigateBackTo()
```

**Note:** Alter the condition `backQueue.size > 2` to achieve desired functionality.
This is tested and working code. Hope this helps.